# How can I make a 'report' button to send a message without going through email?

Tags: html, email, input, submit

What I'm looking for exactly is a button that says something like, "Report a typo," and notifies me when somebody clicks that button on that page.

To clarify, I've got a big writing project with many short pages -- a couple paragraphs in an html template each, which I know could be done much more concisely, but that's another matter. It would help me if, when reading through, I could just click a button every time I (or whoever is reading) see something screwy, then get a message saying on which page the button was clicked without having to send an email. I'm fine with an automatic message to my email (even just as simple as the page name, like 'example.html' in the body), but I don't want to have to open my email client, etc. Honestly, any way I can get notification is fine (can html5 send carrier pigeons?), as long as the user interaction remains minimal. Is there a relatively simple way to do this? I'm happy to learn, but not exactly an expert as it stands.

I apologize in advance if I was unclear, if this has been asked before (I couldn't really think of how to search for what I'm asking), or if the answer is ridiculously simple and I'm just completely missing it. I'm kind of a noob at all this, so I appreciate any patience if this isn't an ideal question, but I'll try to update with suggested fixes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $cell = $this->input->post('cell');
        $msg = $this->input->post('msg');
        //  $captcha=$this->input->post('captcha');
        //  echo $this->session->flashdata('email_sent'); 



        $data = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'cell' => $cell, 'msg' => $msg);

        $this->load->model('mymodel');
        if ($this->mymodel->add($data)) {
            $this->load->library('email');

            //SMTP & mail configuration
            $config = array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'consecutive.development@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'devAccountCB!',
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'utf-8'
            );
            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

            //Email content
            $subject = 'Call Back Request';
            $message = $this->input->post('msg');
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $from = $this->input->post('email');
            $to = 'consecutive.development@gmail.com';

            $this->email->from($from, $name);
            $this->email->to($to);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message("From : " . $from . " <br> Message: " . $message . "<br>Phone Number:" . $cell);


            if ($this->email->send()) {
                $this->mymodel->add($data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Message sent successfully');
     //$success= $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg');     
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Error sending message!');
                //redirect('Welcome/index');
```

//                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                }

```
            echo '<script>alert("Your Message has been sent. Thankyou!");</script>';
            redirect('');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do that in Html5 , however it can be done using Jquery or php, as you may need some backend site scripting language.

Comment: That does help get me started in the right direction, and thanks for the answer. I've used php in some fairly conservative ways; is this something I could do with minimal knowledge and some creative imitation? What I mean is, I know this is a subjective question, but is this going to be more work (for me, given minimal background and that this is a luxury rather than necessity) than it's worth?

Comment: Ben , first thing is that just avoid being so explanatory and detailed questions/answers and second thing if you want a code to understand your requirement then I can give you code in jquery and basic php.
**Kindly accept the answer if my answer helped you out**

Comment: Yes, please; an example would clarify a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Well for that you have to create a simple form in html5 and then enter your details to send mail